# Yammer oAuth invalid redirect_uri

Tags: yammer

I am trying to implement a signin with Yammer button using devise omniauthable. I am following the guide on the github readme.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview 
and
https://github.com/le0pard/omniauth-yammer

In Yammer I have set up my app with a Redirect URI `http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/auth/yammer/callback`.

This is giving me an `invalid redirect_uri` error when I visit `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/yammer`

All the Yammer documentation says the redirect URI should be `https://example.com` but how would that work in development and testing?

This project on github https://github.com/annado/bigboard has it working and I have tried to trace their code ad they suggest having the Redirect URI as `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

So I am just confused? What should the callback URI be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing in Local

redirect_URL = http://localhost:3000/users/auth/

for development replace the localhost:3000 with your domain address.

Comment: Still confused sorry. What about when I am developing and the production server is running and I Yammer is getting requests from both development and production?? :/

Comment: Noob question but... is it just a matter of creating two apps on Yammer. One for production and one for development...

Comment: then you need to create two applications. One for production and another one for development @JayKilleen

Comment: Thanks. That is what I have ended up doing. It makes sense now as the production one gets published on Yammer aswell.